# Pure css conversation

Tags: css

How can I transparent the "red" background in the following code?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrEwyy

```
.from-me {
    position:relative;
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:white; 
    background:#0B93F6;
    border-radius:25px 25px 0 25px;
    float: right;

    &:before {
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-1;
        bottom:-2px;
        right:-7px;
        height:20px;
        border-right:20px solid #0B93F6;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 14px;
        -webkit-transform:translate(0, -2px);
    }

    &:after {
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
        bottom:-2px;
        right:-56px;
        width:26px;
        height:20px;
        background:red;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
    }
}
```

As I want to use background-image in body , I must hide the red background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a different approach to your problem. Instead of removing some part from your blue color box, I created the custom shape in another way. I hope you are trying achieve something like this.

```css
.square{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  float: left
}
.round{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border: solid 100px red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="round"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use two pseudo-elements to create the curl, use one with a radial gradient.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-image: url("https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/images/Background.2e16d0ba.fill-1422x800.jpg");
}

section {
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

section div {
  max-width: 255px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.from-me {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  background: #0B93F6;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0 25px;
  float: right;
}

.from-me:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 14px, #0b93f6 14px);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="from-me">
    <p>Hey there! What's up?</p>
  </div>
</section>
```